# Material-UI Tooltip zIndex over MenuItem in Select component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

My problem is simple, I have a `<Tooltip>` component surrounding a `<Select>` component and when I click the Select, the tooltip shows over the MenuItems like so:

Normal behavour:

[image: Tooltip without MenuItem]

Not so normal behaviour:

[image: Tooltip over MenuItem]

So I left all of the default values for Material-UI and for the Tooltip it's: `zIndex: 1500` but there is none for the MenuItem from what I've seen. I tried to set the zIndex of MenuItem to 1501 but it still has the same behaviour.

I was wondering what's the clean way to either leave the tooltip behind the MenuItem and if that's not possible then to just hide the tooltip when the Select MenuItems are opened...

Here's what my code looks like:

```
<Tooltip title={'Filter by status'}>
    <Select value={this.state.status} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, Filter.Status)}>
        {statuses.sort(this.filterItemSortFn).map(item => {
            return (<MenuItem style={{zIndex: 1501}} value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>);
        })}
    </Select>
</Tooltip>
```

If I set the zIndex of the tooltip to a smaller value and it hides behind the menuItems, but I don't really wanna play with the default values, since it also interferes with other zIndex values.

I made a CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/rn68z4xlo

Comment: Why not set the `z-index` for your menu to something higher like `z-index: 1501` in CSS?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Because even if I do so (I edited the question to include it, thank you) it has the same behaviour.

Comment: Does the `MenuItem` have a `position` set? Try `<MenuItem style={{zIndex: 1501, position: relative}} />`.

Comment: Yeah, even with `style={{zIndex: 1501, position: 'relative'}}`

Comment: `style={{zIndex: 1501+' !important', position: 'relative'}}`

Comment: @Liam zIndex has to be a number `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | "initial" | "inherit" | "unset" | "auto"'.` Even if I force z-index to 1501 in my browser while inspecting the element, the tooltip stays over the MenuItems.

Comment: Can you please show us your code live in CodeSandBox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/rn68z4xlo

Comment: It's because the menu parent has a z-index set to 1300. A child cannot have a z-index greater than their parent. You need to change `.MuiModal-root-57` to have a z-index of 1501.

Comment: How could I possibly edit the zIndex of MuiModal-root-XX if it always changes name and is a default from Material-UI ?

Comment: This will solve your question (if still relevant): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64317706/disable-or-hide-tooltip-without-managing-toottip-state-material-ui/64331130#64331130

Answer (score 9):

Liam's answer is completely incorrect and Joe's is not applicable to MUI v4.

The Tooltip component gets its z-index from the Popper component, so changing the z-index for only the Tooltip will have no effect. You need to pass the z-index up to the Popper from the Tooltip.

Like so:

```
<Tooltip title={"foo"} PopperProps={{style:{zIndex:0}}}>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Material-Ui Tooltip and I guess it's already fixed in the new version

You can fix the problem by adding zIndex to your tooltip

```
  <Tooltip title={"Message"} style={{ zIndex: '1' }}>
        <Select 
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          input={<Input id="select-multiple" />}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map(name => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </Tooltip>
```

Or if you want to hide it completely if the menu open use this code

```
 <Tooltip title={"Message"} 
            onClick={() => this.setState({ tooltip: !this.state.tooltip })}
          style={this.state.tooltip ? {display: 'none'}:{ zIndex: '1' }}>
            <Select 
              value={this.state.name}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              input={<Input id="select-multiple" />}
              MenuProps={MenuProps}
            >
              {names.map(name => (
                <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
                  {name}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </Tooltip>
```

Defined tooltip state

```
class MultipleSelect extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: [],
    tooltip: false,
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/0xrlmv96vl

Comment: I had similar issue with the popper component, my fix was `<Popper style={{zIndex: 1}}>...</Popper>`

Comment: First off you cannot assign a string to zIndex and secondly this will not override its initial zindex.

Answer (score 1):

MUI 5: for some that have problem with modal and tooltip, this will help:

```
 const Tooltiptheme = createTheme({
 components: {
    MuiTooltip: {
      styleOverrides: {
        tooltip: {
          // overrides tooltip
        },
        popper: {
         // overrides the popper
          zIndex: 700 + '!important',
        }
      },
    },
  },
  });
```